# linkedin not getting logged in from yii

Tags: php, yii, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, yii-extensions

i am integrating LinkedIn with yii after successful logged in from yii when i open Linkedin site still it is asking for email and password to login.
below is the code which is used (in controller):

```
if ($eauth->authenticate()) {
                    $identity = new EAuthUserIdentity($eauth);
                    if ($identity->authenticate()) {
                       // Yii::app()->user->login($identity);

                        $this->_process_auth_user($identity->email, $identity->name, $identity->provider);
                    }
```

Where as code in EAuthUserIdentity is:

```
if ($this->service->isAuthenticated) {
            $this->id = $this->service->id;
            $this->name = $this->service->getAttribute('name');
                        $this->email = $this->service->getAttribute('email');
                        $this->provider = $this->service->serviceName;
            $this->setState('id', $this->id);
            $this->setState('name', $this->name);
                        $this->setState('email', $this->email);
            $this->setState('service', $this->service->serviceName);
```

}

i am not copying complete function just showing the main logic.
where i am getting wrong? how i can overcome this issue?